# How to assure equal gap between the buttons when using CSS grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm going to show you a picture, so you can see what I'm trying to achieve. I tapped on a form field and the keyboard on the phone appears. Above the keyboard there are 5 rows with different symbols that are not found on the keyboard. However as you can see only two rows are visible, the second row is not completely visible, but that's not an issue, there is an invisible scroll bar on the right, so I can scroll down and see the other buttons as well.

[image]

I would like to achieve something similar with CSS grid, but since I need to specify a height to have something similar like the image above, only one row and a half visible, the gap between the width and height is different.

Here's my attempt with CSS grid:

[image]

There is more gap between 1 and 2 than 1 and 7. That makes sense since Grid distributes the gap according to the size of the container. However I'm wondering, is there a way to make the gap equal between all buttons?

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 110px;
  overflow: auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 50px);
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 4px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: skyblue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border: none;
  outline-color: #00A8EF;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 37.5em) {
  .grid-container {
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="boxes.css">
  <title>Boxes</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <button class="button button1">1</button>
    <button class="button button2">2</button>
    <button class="button button3">3</button>
    <button class="button button4">4</button>
    <button class="button button5">5</button>
    <button class="button button6">6</button>
    <button class="button button7">7</button>
    <button class="button button8">8</button>
    <button class="button button9">9</button>
    <button class="button button10">10</button>
    <button class="button button11">11</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see on the larger screen where `height: auto` is present, the gap is equal, however on mobile phone is not. Try to reduce the size of the window, then you will see that the gap differs.

I would be grateful for any suggestion.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are setting `justify-content: space-between` on your grid parent. Since you have a fixed width on your grid-items (`50px`), the items are spacing to fill all the remaining visible space. You either need to change how the width is determined for your buttons, or deal with the gap in between or on the right side of the button row (once they wrap).

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 110px;
  overflow: auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 50px);
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: 4px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: skyblue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border: none;
  outline-color: #00A8EF;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 37.5em) {
  .grid-container {
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="boxes.css">
  <title>Boxes</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <button class="button button1">1</button>
    <button class="button button2">2</button>
    <button class="button button3">3</button>
    <button class="button button4">4</button>
    <button class="button button5">5</button>
    <button class="button button6">6</button>
    <button class="button button7">7</button>
    <button class="button button8">8</button>
    <button class="button button9">9</button>
    <button class="button button10">10</button>
    <button class="button button11">11</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By determing the width do you mean to use `calc()`?

Comment: You will have to make a decision as to how many buttons will fill the row on each screen size. You can use `calc()` or a percentage as a base width.

Comment: The problem is with the height. For mobile, I have a height with a specific size, but on large display the height  is set to `auto`.  I updated my question, as you can see there is less gap vertically, that's the issue. On mobile I'd like to have only six squares.

Comment: Ok I managed to fix it somehow with a dirty hack, by setting different grid-gap vertically and horizontally: `grid-gap: 9px 4px;` I was looking for a better solution, though.